# How do I get include diretives to look like `"common/Common.h"` with CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, include, building

I have a C++ project using CMake I want my `#include` to give some idea as to were the thing they are including comes from without having `..`. For the example below I can use `Common.h` from `MainWindow.h` by using either `#include "Common.h"` or `#include "../common/Common.h"` depending on how I set my CMake up.

Is there a way to include `Common.h` from `MainWindow.h` by using `#include "common/Common.h"`aka using a relative path from some base folder (`src` would work)?

The folder structure is roughly:

```
 src:
    common:
        Common.h
    gui:
        MainWindow.h
        MainWindow.cpp
    ...
```

### CMake for `#include "../common/Common.h"` in `stc/gui/MainWindow.h`.

```
 src:
    CMakeLists.txt
    common:
        Common.h
    gui:
        MainWindow.h
        MainWindow.cpp
    ...
```

#### src/CMakeLists.txt

```
# ... CMake boiler plate. ...

add_executable(GUI common/Common.h gui/MainWindow.h gui/MainWindow.cpp)
```

### CMake for `#include "Common.h"`

```
 src:
    CMakeLists.txt
    common:
        CMakeLists.txt
        Common.h
    gui:
        MainWindow.h
        MainWindow.cpp
    ...
```

#### src/common/CMakeLists.txt

```
# ... CMake boiler plate. ...

add_libary(GUICommon Common.h)
```

#### src/CMakeLists.txt

```
# ... CMake boiler plate. ...

add_executable(GUI gui/MainWindow.cpp)

add_subdirectory(common)

target_link_libraries(GUI PRIVATE GUICommon)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need target_include_directories

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the include directories for your GUICommon target.

After the following line:

```
add_libary(GUICommon Common.h)
```

add

```
target_include_directories(GUICommon PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

When you link to `GUICommon` using [target_link_libraries()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) the include directory will be added to the current target since you have the PUBLIC in the [target_include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)